# SpringCloud 2020.0.2 upgrade generates testing error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-test

I'm trying to upgrade a project from SpringCloud BOM `2020.0.1` to `2020.0.2`

When I change the BOM and re-build, I get an error in JUnit tests, saying that the new parameter `spring.config.import` is not set for configserver.

This project is not a ConfigServer, neither use ConfigServer (commented config client)

This is the reported error in tests `contextLoads()`

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    .. Many more
Caused by: org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServerConfigDataMissingEnvironmentPostProcessor$ImportException: No spring.config.import set
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServerConfigDataMissingEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigServerConfigDataMissingEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:100)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:86)
    ... Many more
```

This is my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example.microservices.composite.product'
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone'
    }
}

ext {
   // resilience4jVersion = "1.7.0"
   resilience4jVersion = "1.6.1"

}

dependencies {
    // Local projects dependencies
    implementation project(':api')
    implementation project(':util') 

    // Implementations dependencies
    // Standard (actuator - for monitoring and Health)  
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    // WebFlux (asynchronous Web)
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'

    // SpringFox dependencies
    implementation "io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3+"
    implementation('io.springfox:springfox-spring-webflux:3+')

    // Implementation: Spring cloud
    implementation('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config')
    implementation('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit')
    implementation('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka')

    // Security
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    implementation('org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-resource-server')
    implementation('org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose')

    // CircuitBreaker with Resilience4J
    implementation("io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-spring-boot2:${resilience4jVersion}")
    implementation("io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-reactor:${resilience4jVersion}")
  
    // Implementation: Tracing
    implementation('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth') 

    // Implementation: Performance metrics
    implementation("io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus")
    
    // TEST dependencies
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-test-support')

}


dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        // mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2020.0.1'
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2020.0.2"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

And my contextLoads() method in test class is trivial

```
// Test: Application
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, 
    classes = { 
        ProductCompositeServiceApplication.class,
        TestSecurityConfig.class }, 
    properties = { 
        "spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true" })

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

NOTE: I have also tried defining the `spring.config.import' property to empty or none in the class, with no change

```
@SpringBootTest(
    webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, 
    classes = { 
        ProductCompositeServiceApplication.class,
        TestSecurityConfig.class }, 
    properties = { 
        "spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true",
        "spring.config.import=" })
```

Comment: was there no exception analyzer that had suggestions in the logs?

Comment: I do not know. How can I get this for a spring boot project?

Comment: It would be in the logs

Comment: I have already included the logs (test report). Remember that the fail is during gradle build, in test phase, no running the program.

Comment: FYI, this still continues for spring cloud version 2020.0.3.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have noted the same problem after upgrading to SpringCloud 2020.0.2

Adding `spring.cloud.config.enabled=false` in the tests solved the issue.

E.g.:

```
@SpringBootTest(
  webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT, 
  properties = {"spring.cloud.config.enabled=false"}
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Magnus (and congrats for the book!). I have tried, and this solve the problem with test phase, but now fail the main program. 
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
No spring.config.import property has been defined

Action:

Add a spring.config.import=configserver: property to your configuration.
        If configuration is not required add spring.config.import=optional:configserver: instead.
        To disable this check, set spring.cloud.config.enabled=false or 
        spring.cloud.config.import-check.enabled=false.

Comment: It seems that the springfox project add a dependency with spring-cloud-starter-config, and the config client now has this behaviour. I have added the property to the application.yml for all chapters where config server is not used.

Answer (score 29):

I've faced same issue and resolved by adding bootstrap lib with config lib as follows,

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap'
```

Comment: totally worked for me! thanks

Comment: This definitely solves the problem.  Thanks

Answer (score 21):

i fixed this. adding the dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This fixed my issue

Answer (score 4):

You can disable the import checks by adding these lines to your `application.yml` file in the `test/resources` folder:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
       import-check:
          enabled: false
```

Answer (score 3):

Temporary solution

```
spring.cloud.config.import-check.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 1):

This method work for me:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.spring framework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please note, that this answer has already been given by some of the other posters. In order to keep the site clean and make it easy to find answers, we try to avoid double answers.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your application.yml or application.xml (which is your configuration file is in place and it is able to pull all the configuration